# Is there an npm package available for Angular 5+ to log errors to stackdriver?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I need to log errors from my Angular 5 app.  I found a package for angularjs that logs to stackdriver, but haven't found anything for Angular  2+.  My angular app is running on Firebase hosting.  Any recommendation is appreciated.

Thank you.

I found this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-errors-js package, but it is for angularjs.  I need something for Angular 2+.

Comment: I am also looking for a library that will allow me to log to stack driver via an angular2+ app.

Comment: Same here.  Absolutely no luck in finding clear guidance on configuring client-side app to use Google Cloud logging, or error reporting.